# how many sharing rules can we create at maximum on standard object in salesforce

Tags: sharing-rule

As we all known that we can create 300 Sharing Rules (Both Owner- and Criteria-based) and 50 Sharing Rules (Criteria-based Only) on Custom object. could you please tell anyone how many sharing rules can we create on standard object in Owner based, Criteria-based and Both (Owner - based & Criteria-based).

Thanks in advance

KS Kumaar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is across both Standard and Custom Objects as 300 Maximum rules with 50 Criteria Based rules on Enterprise and Unlimited/Performance Editions only.

[Criteria based rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en) are allowed on some standard objects as well as custom objects

> You can create criteria-based sharing rules for accounts, opportunities, cases, contacts, leads, campaigns, and custom objects. You can create up to 50 criteria-based sharing rules per object.

On an object where the OWD setting is 'Controlled by Parent' you will not be able to set up sharing rules, so you need to change this, e.g on Contact to either 'Private', 'Public Read only' or 'Public Read/Write' to add sharing rules on this specific object.

[image: OWD set to Private rather than Controlled by parent]

Comment: Hi Dave Humm, 
We can create maximum sharing rules in standard object as many as we can create in custom object.
Is it right?

Comment: On the 6 Standard objects listed it will be the full 300 and 50 Criteria based rules. On other Standard Objects the documentation is not giving a clear answer so you may hit a lower limit. However 300 sharing rules is a lot and it would be best to try to avoid that many.

Comment: Hi Dave Humm,
I need one more solution from you as i expecting you will help in this.
I am unable to create sharing rules on contact object where as i can do in other object(standard and custom). i am using developer edition. Salesforce saying that we can create sharing rules on contact in developer edition. 

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_rules_create_contact.htm&language=en
Can you please help me why i am no able to create sharing rules on contact object? do i need any permissions to do this?

Comment: Is that with no list for Contact? That is because the Organisational Wide Default (OWD) is set to 'Controlled by Parent' - see edited answer.