# Can we create more than 100 public groups?

Tags: administration, admin

I want to create more than 100 public group in Enterprise Edition. is ther any governor limits for a public group.

Comment: According to this doc https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_groups_considerations.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.15#firstQueryMeta=%5Bobject%2520Object%5D there's no limit on number of public group. Although there is one limit, don't exceed the nesting by 5 level in your groups

Answer (score 1):

Little googling let me find [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008pwdIAA) that says that there's **no limit to public groups**, but a **limit to 300 sharing rules(and no more than 50 based on criteria based rules)** [which mentioned here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129931/how-many-sharing-rules-can-we-create-at-maximum-on-standard-object-in-salesforce) and that's could be the problem.

**Edited:** As mentioned by *Simon Govaert* the links in the first post are dead. But I did create 5000 groups in my dev org - encountered no problem at all, which partially asserts the statement below that you at least could create 5000 groups.

Comment: Links are dead in the post unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

300 sharing rules and 50 of them criteria based is right. Look at the help page on [Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_about_sharing_rules.htm&type=5).

> NOTE You can define up to 300 total sharing rules for each object, including up to 50 criteria-based or guest user sharing rules, if available for the object.